# Faster Update of Dictionary values

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, key

My dictionary is

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

I'm iterating through an XML file (very large) and saving key/value pairs in a dictionary.

The following snapshot of code is very slow in execution and I want to make it faster. It takes around  more than one hour to complete where my ctr value reaches to 3332130.

```
if (d.ContainsKey(dKey))
{
    dValue = d[dKey];
    d[dKey] = dValue + "," + ctr;
}
else
    d.Add(dKey, ctr.ToString());

ctr++;
```

Comment: This is not enough code to determine why your program runs slow.

Comment: You may want to review the help center on how to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenience as it was my first question on this forum. But really some answers below helped me a lot. Next time I'll try to elaborate as much as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`3332130` is a large number to store in memory, you should not hold such a big collection in memory.

Being said that, Let's try to optimize this.

```
Dictionary<string, StringBuilder>() d = new Dictionary<string, StringBuilder>();
StringBuilder builder;
if (d.TryGetValue(dKey, out builder))
{
    builder.Append(",");
    builder.Append(ctr);
}
else
{
   d.Add(dKey, new StringBuilder(ctr.ToString()));
}
```

1. String concatenation in tight loop is awfully slow, use
   `StringBuilder` instead
2. Use `TryGetValue` which avoids you to call `dValue = d[dKey];`.

I believe this should increase performance significantly.

Comment: Thanks especially for you and others to suggest StringBuilder. My code is now running faster significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a number of repeated concatenations not known at compile time on large strings is an inherently wasteful thing to do.  If you end up concatting a lot of values together, and they are not particularly small, that could *easily* be the source of your problem.

If so, it would have nothing at all to do with the dictionary.  You should consider using a `StringBuilder`, or building up a collection of separate strings that you can join using `string.Join` when you have all of the strings you'll need for that value.

Answer (score 0):

You *may* want to consider using StringBuilders instead of strings:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, StringBuilder>();
```

And append the values like this:

```
if (d.ContainsKey(dKey))
{
    d[dKey].Append("," + ctr);
}
else
    d.Add(dKey, new StringBuilder(ctr.ToString()));
++ctr;
```

But I suspect that the bottleneck is in fact somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to String concatenation enhancements, you can also split your XML into several data sets and then populate *ConcurrentDictionary* in parallel with them. Depending on your data and framework you are using the performance could increase in times.

More examples [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/08/10235147.aspx) and [here](http://blackrabbitcoder.net/archive/2011/02/17/c.net-little-wonders-the-concurrentdictionary.aspx)